# How do you keep track of past/new lab protocols?

Tags: lab-techniques, protocol

Does there exist a list grouped my subject (e.g. 'microscopy') for keeping track of what protocols have been designed and used?

Closest I could find is http://www.protocol-online.org/ but it's fairly sparse and out of date.

Any recommendations/tips and tricks? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best match to what you're looking for is probably https://www.protocols.io/, which hosts protocols for free and generates a digital object identifier (DOI). It is not indexed by PubMed or other similar engines, however.

Some journals permit methods papers, but not a high proportion (and it sounds like you're looking for a place to find them, not to send them).

Comment: Looks interesting – I had in mind that someone would have built a crawler for finding method papers and indexed them, but perhaps not.